# Custom value JSON with select2 v4 ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jquery-select2

I want to grab data other than id or text when an element is selected. The data is retrieved from some source when user puts in some values. All the data fetching and populating works properly. Previously just to get it working, I have just concatenated the "custom" value with some delimiter into the id then later parsed it out, but for the specs of what I want to do, I can't do that anymore. This is basically the code I have so far:

JS:

```
    function convertResult(result) {
            return {
                id: result.p0,
                text: result.p1,
                custom: result.p2
            };
    }

    searchBox.select2({
            width: '100%',
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            placeholder: 'Search',
            ajax: {
                url: {someUrl},
                delay: 350,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function data(params) {
                   return { q: params.term }
                },
                processResults: function processResults(data) {
                   return { results: $.map(data.results, convertResult); }
                }
            }
    });

    searchBox.on("change", function (e) {
         var selVal = $(this).val(); //this gets me the id
         var selText = $(this).text(); //this gets me the text
         // grab the "custom" property from the selected element
   }
```

(cs)HTML:

```
    <div class="form-horizontal">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label class="col-sm-2 control-label> Dropdown </label>
             <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select data-url='@Url.Action("get")' class="form-control ">
                    <option value="" selected="selected"> </option>
                </select>
             </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Readonly Textfield</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control custom" style="width: 100%;" readonly="readonly">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So what I want to do is once an element is selected from the select2 dropdown, populate the readonly textfield with the value saved in custom. When I look at the developer window for my browser I can't seem to find the value on the page. But when debugging, I can see the Json Object with custom value. I have considered scanning through the JSON to find the information I need, but I want to avoid that if possible. How do I go about extracting this information otherwise?